# How would i go about solving this exponential equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2^{ x-2 }+\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { { 4 }^{ x+2 } }  } =\frac { 17 }{ 16 } $$

I can't seem to find any direction to go that will lead me to a solution. I decided to try to take the natural log all terms in the equation to see where that would lead me. Please do not give me the solution. I just want to be put in the right direction so that I could get the solution on my own. Thanks.

This is what I have done so far:

$$ln(2^{ x-2 })+ln(\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { { 4 }^{ x+2 } }  } )=ln(\frac { 17 }{ 16 } )$$

$$(x-2)ln(2)+[ln(1)-ln(\sqrt { { 4 }^{ x+2 } } )]=ln(17)-ln(16)$$

$$xln(2)-2ln(2)+[ln(1)-ln(4\sqrt { { 4 }^{ x } } )]=ln(17)-ln(16)$$

Comment: That manipulation with $\ln$ is a bit off; it seems like you used $\ln(a + b) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$, which isn't typically the case.

Comment: instead, make the substitution $w = 2^x$ and solve for $w.$ If there is any solution with negative $w$ throw it out. So, first, what would you write for $4^x?$

Comment: So when I take the $ln$ of both sides... I have to do it this way? $ln(2^{ x-2 }+\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { { 4 }^{ x+2 } }  } )=ln(\frac { 17 }{ 16 } )$

Comment: @WillJagy Is this correct? $(2^{ 2x })=(2^{ x })^{ 2 }\Rightarrow (4^x)=(w)^2$

Comment: Che, yes, $w^2$ Look at the answers as well, one follows this direction. Either way, what are $2^{x-2}$ and $4^{x+2}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use logarithms at all here-just indices will do.

Note that: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4^{x+2}}}= \frac{1}{2^{x+2}} = \frac{1}{4(2^x)}$$

$$ 2^{x-2} + \frac{1}{2^{x+2}} = \frac{17}{16} $$

$$ \frac{2^x}{4}+ \frac{1}{2^x(4)}= \frac{17}{16}$$

Let $2^x = a$

$$\frac{a}{4}+ \frac{1}{4a}= \frac{17}{16}$$

$$ 4a^2 -17a +4 = 0$$

$$a = 2^{-2}\  \text{or} \ 4 $$

Now substitute the values of $a$ into $2^x = a$ to get the values of $x$.

Comment: I'm confused about one thing in the first line that you wrote.

Isn't $\sqrt { 4^{ x+2 } } =\sqrt { 2^{ 2x }\cdot 4^{ 2 } } =4\cdot 2^{ x }$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, not really. $\sqrt{4^{x+2}} = \left(2^{2(x+2)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}= 2^{x+2}$

Comment: Yes, but $2^{ x+2 }=2^{ x }\cdot 2\cdot 2\Rightarrow 4(2^x)$
You wrote something different on the first line.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, Yes you're right-slight typo there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$2^{x-2}=\frac{1}{4}2^x,\,\sqrt{4^{x+2}}=\sqrt{4^x4^2}=4\sqrt{4^x}=4\sqrt{(2^2)^x}=4\sqrt{2^{2x}}=4\cdot2^x\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall{x}\in\mathbb{R}$$

Now substitute $u=2^x$, have a quadratic and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{x-2}+2^{-(x+2)}=\frac{17}{16}$$
$$2^{x}+2^{-x}=\frac{17}{4}$$
$$2^{x}+\frac{1}{2^{x}}=\frac{17}{4}$$
then assume $y=2^x$ to get 
$$y+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{17}{4}$$
$$y^2+1=\frac{17}{4}y$$